# Alternative to Object.fromEntries?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I receive an `object` like this:

```
this.data = {
    O: {
        id: 0,
        name: value1,
        organization: organization1,
        ...,
       },
    1: {
        id: 1,
        name: value1,
        organization: organization1,
        ...,
        },
    2: {
        id: 2,
        name: value2,
        organization: organization2,
        ...,
        },
    ...
   }
```

I then filter by `id` and remove the `Object` which `id` matches the `id` I receive from the store like so:

```
  filterOutDeleted(ids: any[], data: object,) {
    const remainingItems = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data)
      .filter(([, item]) => !ids.some(id => id === item.id)));

    const rows = Object.keys(remainingItems).map((item) => remainingItems[item]);
    return rows;
  }
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error when building stating `Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'` and I am unable to make changes in the `tsconfig` file at this point. Is there an alternative for `fromEntries` for this case? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the object outside instead, and for every entry that passes the test, assign it to the object manually.

Also note that you can decrease the computational complexity by constructing a Set of the `ids` in advance:

```
const filterOutDeleted = (ids: any[], data: object) => {
  const idsSet = new Set(ids);
  const newObj = {};
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(data)) {
    if (!idsSet.has(val.id)) {
      newObj[key] = val;
    }
  }
  return newObj;
};
```